# Name of movie where astronaut finds a cave or tunnel with displays of artifacts on the inside walls

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the name of a sci fi movie I remember watching late at night when I was probably 8 (1967) so it was probably old at the time. I remember an astronaut finding a cave or tunnel in the side of a mountain, in which he finds lighted displays cut into the walls. I remember the displays were depicting maybe the history of the locals.

That's all I remember, but there was a creepy feel that screams 'you gotta find this movie'.
If that's all I remember from that time, there must be something to it.

Comment: Do you happen to remember if it was in black and white or color?  If it was in color, you might check out the description of Robinson Crusoe on Mars from 1964.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_Crusoe_on_Mars.   I don't remember the exact scene you described, but it has been a few years since I have seen it.  If that doesn't work, you might check out the following Wiki site that lists SF movies from the 50s, 60s, etc.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science-fiction_films_of_the_1950s

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I watched Robinson Crusoe on Mars and although it is not the movie I am thinking of, your reply caused me to watch it for the first time. Thanks very much. I seem to remember color in the movie in question.

Comment: It sounds like the modern movie 'stranded', but it is not old enough for the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think the movie you are rembering is "First Men In The Moon" A British film in colour where the professor invents anti gravity paint. Watched it when I was a kid and is a British movie classic very good motion stop photography for it's time