# 50s or 60s sci fi film about people on alien planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, planets

I remember seeing parts of an old sci fi movie about a group of people on an alien planet. The aliens kind of look like bugs. One of the people in the group is a woman who is trapped by the aliens, and I think they're (the aliens) learning her language.

Comment: Can you recall anything else about this film? Right now these details might match various movies.

Comment: Starship Trooper has that scene too (Woman trapped by the alien which is bugs). but not from 50's-60's

Comment: Bug aliens kidnap human woman in 50's/60's SF movie. Oh yea, this should be easy to find ::facepalm::

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33944/name-of-movie-where-astronaut-finds-a-cave-or-tunnel-with-displays-of-artifacts

Answer (score 5):

There is a scene like that in '[The First Men In The Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Men_in_the_Moon_(1964_film))'.

The story takes place on the moon, the aliens look like stop-motion insects, a woman is captured and held in a transparent cage while the insects try to communicate with her via a flashing crystal.

The insectile aliens can be seen around the minute mark in this trailer: